# Instantialize QApplication outside main function (library)

Tags: c++, qt

I have a c++ library and I plan to add a optional feature to it (enabled by a macro) to show some extra debugging information. The idea is to create and open a window made with Qt to display some data. My problem is that I don't have access to the main function (it is a library) so I can't create the `QApplication` object Qt needs. I have tried creating global objects like this:

```
static int argc = 1;
static char argv[1][6] = {"myapp"};
static QApplication app(argc, (char**)argv);
```

It works but crashes at exit (on `~QApplication()`).

Another option would be allocate the object on heap and have new API methods to initialize/finalize the library. But I don't want to change the API at all.

Yet another would be allocate on heap on the first time I need to open a window and just leak it. But doesn't seems like a good idea.

Any ideas?

I'm using Qt 5.1 with GCC 4.8 targeting Windows and Linux.

Comment: `QApplication::instance()` will give you access to the one defined in main (if there is one) as a QCoreApplication

Comment: The point is that I don't want to force the users of the library to add something their main (or even include Qt at all).

Comment: you are going to need a thread for the event loop that will need to be stopped when the application stops

Answer (score 0):

`Another option would be allocate the object on heap and have new API methods to initialize/finalize the library. But I don't want to change the API at all.` - well don't leak it, have a global heap allocated object and create it when somebody attaches to the library and destroy when the attache detaches. And yeah, the point about the thread is also 100% correct, since attaching/detaching just comes in from the calling thread and you can't block that, you most likely want to spawn of a new thread, allocate the `QApplication` there, maybe even in the threads local stack, and call `run()` there.